# Tomcat 7 URI decoding works differently in Linux and Windows

Tags: tomcat7, utf

I have tomcat7 in Windows 7 and Debian. Both of them have URIEncoding="UTF-8" inside connector. I open url like

```
    http://myhost.com/d/P2ILfNOPL-%2BAp3YljV-axQ
```

and Windows tomcat gives me %2B and Linux decodes it into + sign. I'd like to make them behave in the save way. How? My debug code is:

```
    response.getWriter().write(request.getRequestURI());
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that getRequestURI() is never decoded I should have used getPathInfo() instead.